# visual studio 2012 Content>Themes vs. APP_Themes folders

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I've noticed in VS 2012 that there is a new folder structure called Content>themes>base etc?
What is this for, on ASP.NET web form projects? I've seen a lot of discussion for MVC, but can't find anything for web forms.

Is this new content folder the new way moving forward? How do you access it? Programmatically?
The vs 2012 project still allows the creation of the App_Themes Folder (I'm using 4.5 web forms). And this can be accessed using 'Page.Theme'. I can't figure out how to use the new Content folders?

How do they get deployed and used?

It also appears that the app is defaulting to the Content>themes>site.css file. I can't find anything in my project telling it to? - I did find the ref in the head tag to the css file (duh..).

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same between MVC and Webforms, so any discussion of MVC will more or less be the same.

This is jQuery UI's theme folder.  It's for theming jQuery UI elements.

See http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

No, this is not the "new way moving forward", per se.  jQuery UI does not theme Webforms controls (unless those elements also contain a jQuery UI themable element).  You *CAN* theme your site around jQuery UI theming, but it's not integrated into Webforms like ASP.NET themes.  You would have to style your site manually.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. Good to know Themes are still being used. I find them easy and effective. I programmatically set the masterpage and theme and it makes my life a little simplier.